# Want to convert given format into actual DateTime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert this time format to the actual DateTime format in Python. Hr:Min:Sec in this format. Can Anyone suggest to me how to do it, using pandas?
[image]

Comment: can you provide sample pandas dataframe input?

Answer (score 0):

The pandas function `pd.to_timedelta()` seems to work pretty well on these. That will set it to a timedelta, not a datetime, but it looks like you aren't actually setting things to a date or a time, but rather a duration of time; i.e. a timedelta.

You'll first need to remove the brackets from each element, and then run each column through `pd.to_timedelta()`. Something like this should work, which makes a new `df2`. You could just save it over `df[col]` if you wanted.

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df2[col] = df[col].str.strip('\[\]') #removes the [ and ] characters
    df2[col] = pd.to_timedelta(df2[col])
```

That will give you stuff in this general timedelta style:

```
                0               1
0 0 days 00:10:00 0 days 00:20:00
1 0 days 01:00:00 0 days 03:00:00
```

From there, you can tinker with the format as needed for what specifically you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to remove the square braces as they are reserved for optional parts (I personally haven't found a way to escape them):

```py
pd.to_timedelta(df['x'].str.strip('[ ]'))
```